# How to duplicate the output based on the number of lines

Tags: shell

I have a scenario to duplicate the values of the second command based on the output of the 1st command result.

Below is the example:

1st command output:

```
/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part01-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018
/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part02-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018
/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part03-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018
```

2nd command output:

```
raam
```

expected result:
I need to combine both the results and need to duplicate the value of the 2nd command as shown below

```
/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part01-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018,raam
/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part02-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018,raam
/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part03-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018,raam
```

Comment: If 2nd command output is in 2 lines then what will be final output?

Comment: Yes good question. Actually the values should append for the specific 2nd command output. for ex: 

/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part01-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018,raam
/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part02-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018,raam
/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part03-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018,raam

/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part01-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018,raam

/xyx/assigned/2018/sample/part03-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018,xyx
/xyx/assigned/2018/sample/part03-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018,xyx

Comment: You could try `sed "s/^.*$/&,$(2ndCommand)/" < <(1stCommand)` where command and process substitution are used fill in your data. But, if your 2ndCommand outputs more than a single line, you will have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is with `sed`. So long as your 2nd Command only has a single output your can use *command substitution* with the 2nd Command and *process substitution* with the 1st Command and `sed` using the substitution form and append a comma and the output from the 2nd Command to the end, e.g.

```
sed "s/^.*$/&,$(./2ndcmd.sh)/" < <(./1stcmd.sh)
```

Where the `1stcmd.sh` file provides the following output:

```
$ ./1stcmd.sh
/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part01-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018
/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part02-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018
/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part03-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018
```

and the `2ndcmd.sh` file provides the following output:

```
$ ./2ndcmd.sh
raam
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed "s/^.*$/&,$(./2ndcmd.sh)/" < <(./1stcmd.sh)
/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part01-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018,raam
/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part02-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018,raam
/raam/assigned/2018/sample/part03-examples.csv,100,20-jun-2018,raam
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

(since `< <(...)` is a bashism, if you need POSIX shell compatibility, you could do:

```
$ ./1stcmd.sh | sed "s/^.*$/&,$(./2ndcmd.sh)/"
```

and pipe the information to your `sed` command)

Answer (score 1):

Simple for BASH:

```
for i in `1st command`; do  echo $i,$(2nd command); done
```